ARM template spec error "Unable to retrieve the template artifact"
I got an error when I tried to deploy using template spec from Azure CLI.
The error message was Unable to retrieve the template artifact.
Template spec name is test and main template and linked template is saved on local PC.
I will share main template and the path of each templates(main and linked templates).
main_template.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env":{
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "storage",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/linkedtemplate_storage.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "env": {
                      "value": "[parameters('env')]"
                  },
                  "location": {
                      "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "monitoring",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/linkedtemplate_monitoring.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "env": {
                      "value": "[parameters('env')]"
                  },
                  "location": {
                      "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "notification",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/linkedtemplate_notification.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "env": {
                      "value": "[parameters('env')]"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

path
main: "C:\Users\template\maintemplate.json"
linked(Storage): "C:\Users\template\linked\linkedtemplate_storage.json"
linked(Monitoring): "C:\Users\template\linked\linkedtemplate_monitoring.json"
`linked(Nortification): "C:\Users\template\linked\linkedtemplate_notification.json"
And here is deploy command.
$id = $(az ts show --name test --resource-group rg-nonprod-japan-rubiconclientbridge01-na-idbridge-n01-devops --version "1.0" --query "id")

az deployment group create \
  --resource-group rg-nonprod-japan-rubiconclientbridge01-na-idbridge-n01-infrastructure \
  --template-spec $id \
  --parameters "@.\maintemplate.parameters-dev.json" \

I think linked template path is correct in the main template so I don't know why that error has occurred.
Anyone know how should I do?
Any answer would be helped, if you want more information please don't hesitate to ask me.
Thank you.

Have you checked all the linked templates existed properly in the given paths! @CuteeeeRabbit

I also received the same error when executing the deployment with the given commands. "Unable to retrieve the template artifact" issue might come when the linked templates are not properly accessible from the Azure az ts show command.
There could be couple of reasons for this not to work as expected.
Firstly, retrieving template spec ID is working fine but when it is passing to the az deployment  group create command, make sure the template spec ID is reading properly.
I tried to pass it directly as shown below rather than retrieving it from az ts show to find out if the issue is with either of the command. It worked as expected without any conflict.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "storage",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "storage.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "location": {
                      "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "monitoring",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "monitor.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "location": {
                      "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

az deployment group create --resource-group ipresources --template-spec "/subscriptions/xxxx/res
ourceGroups/ipresources/providers/Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/secondtemp/versions/1.0" --template-file "linkedtemp.json"


Also, the issue might be with the relative path field of templateLink block. The alternative is to use the ID of a template spec of storage account and monitoring Json template separately in order to avoid the confusion here.
Create a ts spec with az ts create for a storage account first and do the same for monitoring template as well. Now pass the IDs of each individual template spec under template Link ID field as shown below.
"templateLink": {
   "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/ipresources/providers/Microsoft.Resources/templateSpecs/secondtemp/versions/1.0"
  }

Or
According to this MSDoc, you can also uri field under templateLink for deployment by providing a GitHub Uri or a blob Uri after uploading the file contents (Json). Refer to the given MS Doc for clear procedure.
"templateLink": {
   "uri": "blob uri or Git Uri"
  }

